# How to sort an array according to user-defined criteria without using comparator in java?

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, intellij-idea

I want to sort the class's field according to employee experience, and then sort to descending order according to employee id. Code is defined as below:
But I don't want to use a comparator or the other library. Can we do it with a logic importing using external library or packages

```
package practicequestion;

import java.util.Scanner;
import practicequestion.employeeq.Employee;

public class EmployeeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee[] obj = new Employee[3];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of inputs you want ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter FirstName");
            String firstname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter LastName");
            String lastname = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Email");
            String email = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Salary");
            int salary = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Mobile Number");
            long mobileno = sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println("Enter Experience");
            int empexp = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Employee Id");
            int empid = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            if (i < n) {
                obj[i] = new Employee(firstname, lastname, email, salary, empid, empexp, mobileno);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("\nEmployee " + (i+1) +  " values are: ");
            obj[i].Display();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();   
        }
    }

}
```

Its class is defined as below:

```
package practicequestion.employeeq;

public class Employee {
   String FirstName;
   String LastName;
   String Email;
   int Salary;
   long MobileNo;
   int EmployeeExp;
   int EmployeeId;

    public Employee(String FirstName, String LastName,String Email,int Salary,int EmployeeId,int EmployeeExp,long MobileNo) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Salary = Salary;
        this.EmployeeId = EmployeeId;
        this.EmployeeExp = EmployeeExp;
        this.MobileNo = MobileNo;
    }
    public void Display() {
        System.out.println(FirstName +"\n" + LastName + "\n" + Email + "\n" + Salary + "\n"+ EmployeeExp +"\n" + EmployeeId +"\n" + MobileNo);
    }
}
```

**Please help me it would be very helpful.**

Comment: So you want to write your own sorting algorithm implementation? Is that it? If yes, what is stopping you from doing so?

Comment: If you are not allowed to implement a `Comparator` and are not allowed t modify `Employee` to be `Comparable` so that it can be used with the [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) function, then you'll have to write the sorting function yourself. Perhaps that is the point of the exercise?

Comment: What's the motivation of not using `Comparator`? That class is built *exactly* for what you want to do and avoiding it just makes the task unnecessarily harder.

Comment: oh...ok i understood. Actually I have been given an assignment  and in my class comparator is not covered yet and I have to do the assignment so I can't use it right now.